# How do I automatically delete all the github generated patch branches from a fork

Tags: git, github

Every time I make typo corrections when reading other people's github repositories, a branch is created in my repository and they pile up because I never return to the pull request to delete them. I currently have 9 branches with the title patch-1, patch-2... etc... and I'm too lazy to delete them one by one. How can I automatically delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command I wrote:

```
git push --delete origin `git branch -r --list 'origin/patch*' | sed 's/origin\/\(.*\)/\1/'`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a general script that will delete all merged branches (either locally or remotely, I have a [utility script](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/master/utils/scripts/git-delete-merged) to do just that). To delete all local branches that have been merged:

```
git-delete-merged --doit --local
```

To delete all remote branches on `origin` matching the regex `"patch-"`:

```
git delete-merged --remote origin --match "patch-" --doit
```

If you don't want to add a script for a one-off need you can find what you need for a specific one-liner in the source.